# When selecting the options in mat-select there is no output

Tags: angular, typescript, select, angular-material

I have integrated a function in my select where all options are selected. The selection works, but the selected sections are not shown. Without the all select function my select works fine. Do you know where my error is?

My work in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-spp6wg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

My Code:

Select

```
<mat-select [(value)]="selectedValues" formControlName="dashboardValue" multiple>
   <mat-option class="dashboard-select-option" *ngFor="let dashboardPosition of displayDashboardValues" 
      [value]="dashboardPosition.key" (click)="togglePerOne(allSelected.viewValue)">
      {{ dashboardPosition.viewValue }}
   </mat-option>
   <mat-option #allSelected (click)="toggleAllSelection()" [value]="0">Alle</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Output

```
<div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="selectedValue['valuePositionType'] === 'profit-loss-area'">
   <app-profit-loss-area></app-profit-loss-area>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="selectedValue['valuePositionType'] === 'cash-area'">
   <app-cash-area></app-cash-area>
 </div>
```

TS

```
 public displayDashboardValues = [
    {key:'1', valuePositionType: 'profit-loss-area', viewValue:'Ergebnis'},
    {key:'2', valuePositionType: 'cash-area', viewValue:'Cash'},
  ]; 

// Dashboard form
    this.dashboardForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      dashboardValue: [null]
    });

// Select options
  togglePerOne(all){
    if (this.allSelected.selected) {
      this.allSelected.deselect();
      return false;
    }
    if(this.dashboardForm.controls.dashboardValue.value.length==this.displayDashboardValues.length)
      this.allSelected.select();
  }

  toggleAllSelection() {
    if (this.allSelected.selected) {
      this.dashboardForm.controls.dashboardValue
        .patchValue([...this.displayDashboardValues.map(item => item.key), 0]);
    } else {
      this.dashboardForm.controls.dashboardValue.patchValue([]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) if your request is satisfied!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `dashboardPosition.key` as `value`, your `ngIf` check `selectedValue['valuePositionType'] === 'profit-loss-area'` can not work any longer, because you have only the selected keys in your `selectedValues` list. Just try to add `{{selectedValues}}` to see whats happen. Another issue is your `[value]="0"` which seems to be a c&p fragment.

As one possible solution i would suggest following changes:

First of all here is a working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-hcoekm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

#### Component

- add a dummy entry to your `displayDashboardValues` for select all
- use a plain boolean for `allSelected`
- just set the `selectedValues` in your `toggleAllSelection`

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  dashboardForm: FormGroup;
  selectedValues: any;
  allSelected = false;

   public displayDashboardValues = [
    {key:'0', valuePositionType: 'undefined', viewValue:'Alle'},
    {key:'1', valuePositionType: 'profit-loss-area', viewValue:'Ergebnis'},
    {key:'2', valuePositionType: 'cash-area', viewValue:'Cash'},
    {key:'3', valuePositionType: 'balance-area', viewValue:'Bilanz'},
    {key:'4', valuePositionType: 'staff-area' ,viewValue:'Mitarbeiter'},
    {key:'5', valuePositionType: 'divisions-area', viewValue:'Sparten'},
    {key:'6', valuePositionType: 'commisions-area', viewValue:'Aufträge'},    
  ];

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
     // Dashboard form
    this.dashboardForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      dashboardValue: [null]
    });
  }

  toggleAllSelection() {
      this.allSelected = !this.allSelected;  // to control select-unselect
      this.selectedValues = this.allSelected ? this.displayDashboardValues : [];
    }
}
```

#### Template

- as `mat-option` only show values with `key > 0` as default
- add another `mat-option` with your custom value (as you did before) and link it your `toggleAllSelection`

```
<mat-select  [(value)]="selectedValues" (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)" formControlName="dashboardValue" multiple>
          <div *ngFor="let dashboardPosition of displayDashboardValues">
            <mat-option class="dashboard-select-option" *ngIf="dashboardPosition.key>0" [value]="dashboardPosition">
              {{ dashboardPosition.viewValue }}
            </mat-option>
          </div>
          <mat-option [value]="displayDashboardValues[0]" (click)="toggleAllSelection()">{{ displayDashboardValues[0].viewValue }}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
```